# how to print textbox value in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my code,when any text is entered into the textbox and click on `add attribute` button, entered value displayed on page for two times, one in `first row of table` and another one is in `first row of second table`. Now question is, when i entered text into another textbox which is in `second row of second table`, it should display the entered text.but it can't display. it is not working.

```
<script>
var i = 0;
document.getElementById('add-val').innerHTML='';
function insRow()
{
    i++;

    var x=document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow(-1)  
    var a=x.insertCell(-1)

    var txt=document.getElementById('add-val').value;
    a.innerHTML=txt;

// for <tr> of table    
    var row = document.getElementById("myRow");
    var newrow=document.getElementById("myRow1");
    var x = row.insertCell(-1);
    var y = newrow.insertCell(-1);
    x.innerHTML=txt; //+ '<br>' + 
    y.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="nm" />';
}

document.getElementById('add-val').innerHTML='';
</script>
```

& this is html code.

```
<form method="post" name="form">
<input type="text" name="attr" id="add-val"> <input type="button" onClick="insRow()" value="Add Attribute">
<table width="27" height="17" id="myTable">    </table>
<table cellpadding="13px">
<tr id="myRow">   </tr>
<tr id="myRow1">      </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Add option" onClick="insRow()"/>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$val= $_POST['add'];
echo $val;
}
?> 
</form>
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but you don't seem to have any element named 'add', so $_POST['add'] will always be empty.

Comment: Ohh kindly sorry, i forget to change it's value.    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $val= $_POST['nm'];
    echo $val;
    }
    ?>

Comment: Yes, this will get you one value...from the first generated field.....  But what if you wanna click the add attributes button multiple times and generate multiple fields... then my answer will be how you do that.

Comment: @KyleK Actually you asked the correct question & that is what i need. When i clicked on add attributes button multiple times, number of textboxes are displayed in same row. When i entered different text in each textbox, it should displayed in another row. it's not working.

Comment: Did you try my answer? You need to be storing the values in an array and then when you retrieve with $_POST, loop through them and display

Comment: Yes. i tried it, but it's not working.

Comment: Also. Do you expect it to display without a refresh/form submit?  Because it wont.  And if thats what you want, you need to use javascript for that

Comment: When you click on add option button, to save/display the multiple textboxes value, the page gets automatically refreshed(bz of form submitting), again it doesn't expect to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
   y.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="nm[]" />';
```

The []'s after nm

```
 name="nm[]"
```

Serve to store all new generated fields into an array, which can then be accessed by $_POST

Which you then just access like so....

```
    $val = $_POST['nm'];

    foreach($val as $v){
        echo $v; // display what user entered
     }

    // var_dump($val) will show you all the users seperate input for each field
```

Comment: what about it is not working?? You have to be more clear

Comment: Are you preventingDefault(); on you insROW() button?  Beause you need to be appending the rows without refresh, and then when you click submit, it should display all that you enteres

Comment: when text is entered into multiple textboxs  of second row of second table, & click on Add Option button, it didn't display any value.

Comment: Yes, because it will only display when you submit the form.  Not after each row add.  If you want it to display on each row add, you need to use javascript and possibly AJAX

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Code :**

```
<form method="post" name="form">
    <input type="text" name="attr" id="add-val"> <input type="button" onClick="insRow()" value="Add Attribute">
    <table width="27" height="17" id="myTable">    </table>
    <table cellpadding="13px">
    <tr id="myRow">   </tr>
    <tr id="myRow1">      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Add option" onClick="insRow()"/>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $val= $_POST['nm'];
    echo $val;
    }
    ?> 
</form>
```

put the name of input whos value you want to print in place of **attr**

```
$val= $_POST['attr'];
```

Comment: no @J Prakash, i am talking about the second textbox. The second textbox will come when we clicked on     Add Attribute button. As we enter any text into that second textbox, it should display the text, but it is not working.

Comment: Thank you @J Prakash, but when we clicked on add attribute button multiple times, it display multiple textbox. If I entered text in every textboxes & click on 'add option' button, the value should display in different variable.